# Understanding SQL editor

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

I am new to database.I am using sql*plus and have installed oracle 10g. In the current version I am not able to go back in a line using arrow keys and rectify the mistake I have committed. I also cannot use the up arrow keys to trace back the previous commands. All I can do is use a '/' to get to the previous command.I along with many others have this question

Question is : Why can't i go back and edit using arrow keys while i haven't press enter? What has gone into making of this editor and why have the designers decided to make it so?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Save yourself the grief.  Use sql developer instead.  It's a free download from oracle.

Comment: I just want to know whether was there a genuine reason for doing this or was it unintentional so I posted this question.

Comment: [Couple of other ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/286091/266304), though it's really off-topic. No-one here is likely to know how Oracle decided on the features in any of its tools, though it's worth bearing in mind that SQL*Plus has been around for a *long* time and needs to be stable and reliable above all else IMO, so there probably hasn't been much incentive to add extras to it. Once you add one nice thing everyone else wants something else. Efforts at 'better' clients have focused on SQL Developer and to some extent OEM.

Comment: The commandline history in SQL*Plus depends on the operating system. It works quite well on Windows. For Linux based systems search for "sqlplus readline rlwrapper"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlplus is more aimed on running scripts than being a friendly user interface for the database. If you still want to use SQL*plus as an user interface and also want cursor navigation and history enabled, you could wrap it up in rlwrap as described here [Command history in sqlplus using a linux shell: rlwrap](http://moinne.com/blog/ronald/oracle/command-history-in-sqlplus-using-a-linux-shell-rlwrap)

Smarter would be to go to [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) which is a pretty good and friendly GUI for the Oracle database.

A very nice third party - multi database - GUI would be [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/features/) that also runs on mulitple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use SQL*Plus, type `EDIT` in the SQL*Plus window to open the last-run script in Notepad.  Write your script there, save it, then type <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>when you're back in SQL*Plus to execute the script.

Comment: I am getting this:SP2-0110: Cannot create save file "afiedt.buf"

Comment: Also it would be nice if you would tell why did the designers made it so

Comment: The error means that you can't write to the current working directory.  Either start SQL*Plus from someplace else, or specify the temp file with `set editfile=c:\temp\whatever.txt`.

Comment: I could only speculate as to why the feature isn't there.  SQL*PlusW (which I assume is what you're using) is not a FSE; it's really just a windowed version of the command-line sqlplus.exe.  SQL*PlusW isn't even included with 11G.

Comment: ok thanks.In between if you have any links citing the exact reason feel free to share.